# beyondcode\laravel-websockets it is redirecting to wss instead of ws on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, laravel-websockets

I am using laravel version 5.7 and beyondcode\laravel-websockets package v1.3 the problem I am facing right now is when I am running it on localhost I am getting this error

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost/app/somekey?protocol=7&client=js&version=6.0.2&flash=false' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

I have changed encrypted to false in bootsrap.js still it connects to wss instead of ws

bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: false,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true
});
```

broadcasting.php config

```
'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => false,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http'
            ],
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to the config,dont forget to compile

```
enabledTransports: ['ws'],
```

If this doesnt work try to downgrade pusher.js to 4.3

Answer (score -2):

In case somebody else sees this, I've solved it once I stopped going through https://www.mypage.com and use http://www.mypage.com

Just change the protocol on your browser from https to http